# How to return an array after a function?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I manage to make my array work on the console.

When I click the button the array shows on console, but not on my html.

**TS:**

```
jogar(){
 for(var u=0;u<6;u++){        
     this.y = Math.ceil(Math.random()*59+1);
     this.random.push(this.y);           
    };
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<ion-card-content>        
    <button ion-button color="secondary" (click)="jogar()">Jogar</button>
    <p>{{random}}</p>        
</ion-card-content>
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

you should use `ngFor` directive to show the values

```
 <p *ngFor="let r of random">{{r}}</p>
```

Comment: This works! Thanks you.

On the same subject, how I'm supposed to make the array empty after show?

Comment: it's not clear how you would like to do it, but I use router outlet

Comment: I'm trying this:
`this.random.splice(0, this.random.length);`

This way the array should empty after reaching 6 in lenght.

Comment: it's only removing elements of the array, it won't change the view. Additionally you may try to apply a structural directive, i.e. `ngIf` on the container.